# how to compute $\lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]} \cos (\frac{k \pi}{n}) $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I compute the following limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\lbrack \frac{n}{2}\rbrack} \cos (\frac{k \pi}{n}) $$
I tried to solve the problem by considering two cases, first by taking n is even and then by taking n as odd integer.
When n is even then the limit transforms to $$\lim_{2n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos (\frac{k \pi}{2n})=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2}) \,dx=\frac1\pi$$
But when n is odd then the limit transforms to $$\lim_{2n+1 \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos (\frac{k \pi}{2n+1})$$
which I cannot convert to Riemann-sum. Please help, if I can convert it to Riemann-sum or is there any other way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both cases are Riemann sums for
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\cos(\pi\,x)\,dx=\frac{|}{\pi}.
$$
Remember that in the Riemann sum the point of evaluation can be any point in a subinterval of the partition, not necessarily one of the extremes.