Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$
Evaluate $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)
$$
Ans $$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^{{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}\cos(\pi x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\pi}(\sin \pi x)_1^{{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}$$
How to proceed, then?

Well, $$\left\lfloor\frac{2n+1}2\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{2n}2\right\rfloor=n,\forall n\in\Bbb N,$$ so you're looking at the sequence $\left(\lfloor\sin(n\pi)\rfloor\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}.$ Does it converge?

please write in answer style

What is the sum of cosines with angles in arithmetic progression ? This would give you more than the limit.

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2336563/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016668/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3358375/42969.

This limit can be solved easily by transforming it into the following definite integral: $\int_0^{1/2} \cos(\pi \, x) ~ dx = 1/\pi$.

Please explain why the upper limit becomes 1/2
